# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'moviepy' although it is installed

Tags: python, moviepy, modulenotfounderror

I'm working with Python 3.10.11 on Windows 11 using freshly created venv. I installed moviepy using pip, now if I do

```
(venv) PS D:\Projects\bot for circles\Telegram-Video-Circle-Bot> pip list
```

I get

```
------------------- ---------
anyio               4.0.0
certifi             2023.7.22
charset-normalizer  3.3.2
colorama            0.4.6
decorator           4.4.2
exceptiongroup      1.1.3
h11                 0.14.0
httpcore            0.18.0
httpx               0.25.0
idna                3.4
imageio             2.31.6
imageio-ffmpeg      0.4.9
moviepy             1.0.3
numpy               1.26.1
opencv-python       4.8.1.78
Pillow              10.0.1
pip                 23.0.1
proglog             0.1.10
python-telegram-bot 20.6
requests            2.31.0
setuptools          65.5.0
sniffio             1.3.0
tqdm                4.66.1
urllib3             2.0.7
```

So moviepy is in the list. But when I try to import it, it just not working:

```
(venv) PS D:\Projects\bot for circles\Telegram-Video-Circle-Bot> python
Python 3.10.11 (tags/v3.10.11:7d4cc5a, Apr  5 2023, 00:38:17) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import moviepy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'moviepy'
>>>
```

What can I do to fix it?

I worked without using venv, when I got that error first time, now I switched to venv and created new enviroment, then installed all packages that I needed. It is error that occurs with moviepy specifically, for example, numpy works perfectly:

```
(venv) PS D:\Projects\bot for circles\Telegram-Video-Circle-Bot> python
Python 3.10.11 (tags/v3.10.11:7d4cc5a, Apr  5 2023, 00:38:17) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.arange(0, 10, 11)
array([0])
```

Comment: What do you get if you do `python -m pip list` instead of `pip list`?

Comment: exactly matching list, moviepy is in both

Answer (score 0):

I think your PATH is declared in the wrong way. Your path will have pattern like
/path/to/A/bin:/path/to/B/bin:/path/to/your/venv/bin

So the `python` command will exist in also your `path/to/A` and your `venv`, but it come from `/path/to/A`, then the OS will get the python executed file in `/path/to/A/bin` instead of `/path/to/your/venv/bin` - which contains the python version that included `moviepy`.

Verify my idea by using `where python` vs `where pip` command

There is 2 way to fix it:

- use `python -m pip install moviepy`, then use `python main.py` as usual (recommend for newbie)
- Fix the PATH and move your venv path to the head of PATH variables

Good luck

Comment: Thank you! I', not shure about the PATH because this issue occered before I tried it with venv.

Tried use `where` commands and got this:


(venv) D:\Projects\bot for circles>where python
D:\Projects\bot for circles\venv\Scripts\python.exe
C:\Python310\python.exe
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

(venv) D:\Projects\bot for circles>where pip
D:\Projects\bot for circles\venv\Scripts\pip.exe
C:\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe

p.s. That comments formatting is terrible, hope it is readable...